# Condition in HAVING faster than same condition in WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, having

I came across a query that had a condition in the HAVING section of the query that I would have typically placed in the WHERE section. I preceded to move the condition to the WHERE section and to my surprise the code runs about 200%+ longer using WHERE instead of HAVING.

This seamed odd to me and I have yet to be able to find anything online that describes this.

Here is an example of how the query is laid out:

This query runs in 50 to 55 seconds consistently.

```
SELECT TB1.COL1
    ,TB1.COL2
    ,TB2.COL3
    ,TB3.COL4
    ,TB1.SOME_ID
FROM TABLE1 TB1
JOIN TABLE2 TB2
JOIN TABLE3 TB3
    ON TB1.SOME_ID = TB2.SOME_ID
    ON TB1.SOME_ID = TB3.SOME_ID
GROUP BY TB1.COL1, TB1.COL2, TB2.COL3, TB3.COL4, TB1.SOME_ID
HAVING TB1.SOME_ID = 9999999
```

However this query runs in 120 to 130 seconds consistently.

```
SELECT TB1.COL1
    ,TB1.COL2
    ,TB2.COL3
    ,TB3.COL4
    ,TB1.SOME_ID
FROM TABLE1 TB1
JOIN TABLE2 TB2
JOIN TABLE3 TB3
    ON TB1.SOME_ID = TB2.SOME_ID
    ON TB1.SOME_ID = TB3.SOME_ID
WHERE TB1.SOME_ID = 9999999
GROUP BY TB1.COL1, TB1.COL2, TB2.COL3, TB3.COL4, TB1.SOME_ID
```

I am confused as to why the HAVING would ever run quicker than the WHERE statement for this kind of condition. I mean its not an aggregate or anything so I would normally use WHERE in this case but testing has shown this to be slower...

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:

Here is the original query, Please note I did not write this query and it does work just fine. I am simply tying to understand why the HAVING is faster than using the same condition in WHERE:

```
SELECT TB1.COL1
,TABLE302.COL2
,TABLE314.COL3
,TABLE314.COL4
,TABLE312.COL5
,TABLE314.COL6
,TABLE302.COL7
,TABLE320.COL8
,TABLE320.COL9
,TABLE302.COL10
,TABLE302.COL11
,TABLE230.COL12
,TABLE100.COL13
,TABLE100.COL14
,TABLE104.COL15
,TABLE110.COL16
,TABLE230.COL17
,TABLE230.COL18
,TB1.COL19
,IIf([TABLE230.CD]>'     '
    And format(cast(TABLE230.DT as date),'yyyy-MM-dd') = format(cast('12/31/9999' as date),'yyyy-MM-dd'), TABLE230.AMT,TB1.O) AS [FA]
,TABLE230.COL20
,TABLE230.COL21
,format(cast(DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as date),'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [TODAY]
,TABLE104.COL22
,TABLE320.COL23
,TABLE180.COL24
,Count(TABLE100.COL14) AS [COUNT_COL14]
,IIf(format(cast(TABLE230.FDT as date),'yyyy-MM-dd') = format(cast('1/1/1901' as date),'yyyy-MM-dd')
    And format(cast(TABLE230.DDT as date),'yyyy-MM-dd') = format(cast('1/1/1901' as date),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'NOT ACTIVE','ACTIVE') AS [ST]
,TABLE230.COL25
FROM TABLE1 TB1
RIGHT JOIN TABLE302 
INNER JOIN TABLE114 
INNER JOIN TABLE130 
INNER JOIN TABLE110 
INNER JOIN TABLE126
INNER JOIN TABLE104
INNER JOIN TABLE124
INNER JOIN TABLE400
INNER JOIN TABLE120
ON TABLE400.CYP = TABLE120.CYP
INNER JOIN TABLE100
ON TABLE120.PID = TABLE100.COL13
ON TABLE124.PID = TABLE100.COL13
INNER JOIN TABLE230
ON TABLE120.PID = TABLE230.PID
AND TABLE120.CYP = TABLE230.CYP
ON TABLE104.PID = TABLE230.PID
AND TABLE104.PID = TABLE124.PID
ON TABLE126.PID = TABLE104.PID
ON TABLE110.EID = TABLE230.EID
AND TABLE110.EID = TABLE126.EID
ON TABLE130.GCD = TABLE230.GCD
AND TABLE130.EID = TABLE110.TID
ON TABLE114.GCD = TABLE130.GCD
ON TABLE302.COL7 = TABLE230.LD
AND TABLE302.COL10 = TABLE400.HP
AND TABLE302.COL11 = TABLE400.SP
INNER JOIN TABLE180
INNER JOIN TABLE320
ON TABLE180.RN = TABLE320.COL23
ON TABLE302.COL7 = TABLE320.CID
INNER JOIN TABLE314
ON TABLE302.ZID = TABLE314.COL4
ON TB1.COL1 = TABLE230.GCD
LEFT JOIN TABLE312
ON TABLE314.COL4 = TABLE312.TID
GROUP BY TB1.COL1
,TABLE302.COL2
,TABLE314.COL3
,TABLE314.COL4
,TABLE312.COL5
,TABLE314.COL6
,TABLE302.COL7
,TABLE320.COL8
,TABLE320.COL9
,TABLE302.COL10
,TABLE302.COL11
,TABLE230.COL12
,TABLE100.COL13
,TABLE100.COL14
,TABLE104.COL15
,TABLE110.COL16
,TABLE230.COL17
,TABLE230.COL18
,TB1.COL19
,IIf([TABLE230.CD]>'     '
    And format(cast(TABLE230.DT as date),'yyyy-MM-dd') = format(cast('12/31/9999' as date),'yyyy-MM-dd'), TABLE230.AMT,TB1.O)
,TABLE230.COL20
,TABLE230.COL21
,format(cast(DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as date),'yyyy-MM-dd')
,TABLE104.COL22
,TABLE320.COL23
,TABLE180.COL24
,IIf(format(cast(TABLE230.FDT as date),'yyyy-MM-dd') = format(cast('1/1/1901' as date),'yyyy-MM-dd')
    And format(cast(TABLE230.DDT as date),'yyyy-MM-dd') = format(cast('1/1/1901' as date),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'NOT ACTIVE','ACTIVE')
,TABLE230.COL25
,TABLE230.FDT
,TABLE230.MDT
,TABLE230.NCD
,TABLE114.GCD
,TABLE230.MDT
HAVING TABLE314.COL4 = 99999999  -- If I move this line to WHERE it runs 2x longer
and format(cast(TABLE230.MDT as date),'yyyy-MM-dd') > format(cast('12/31/2019' as date),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

The execution plan appear to be different as well.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204511/discussion-on-question-by-mike-smt-condition-in-having-faster-than-same-condit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the execution plan.  You would have to look at the execution plans for two two queries to spot the differences.

In my experience, the difference is often due to the ability to use an index for the `GROUP BY`.  The filtering in the `WHERE` prevents the use of the index.  However, that is not the case for your query because it is aggregating by columns from multiple tables.

Another possibility is that the filter removes relatively few records, but affects the execution plan of the `JOIN`s.  I suspect this is the cause of what you are seeing.  You would need to look at the execution plan to see if the joins are the same.

Comment: I have added the original query for as I am sure something got lost in translation when I tried to reduce it for the post.

Comment: @Mike-SMT . . . You'll notice that with the `WHERE` clause, it is doing a nested loops join.  That is usually a performance kills.  You can use an option to disallow nested loops and you might get faster performance with the `WHERE`.

Comment: Oh I am not familiar with nested loops. When I get into work tomorrow I will look up those options and see how that goes. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the filter on the where clause should be faster, especially with aggregations (the soonest the filter is applied the faster the aggregation). However, your query is not a typical or better a "local" one. You are joining tables of linked servers and when dealing with linked servers the "topological where"/which side the filter is applied is important (is it applied on the local server or passed through to the linked server?).

From the picture of the execution plans, there are 3 remote tables and 1 local table (assuming the execution plans are for the same query and only the placement of the filter is changed in the query). 
The first plan, for the HAVING does not have 3 remote operators. This means that one of the remote operators is actually a join (at the remote side) of two tables, this most likely is the very first remote operator(98%). Notice that there is no filter, so a join of two tables at the remote side and ALL rows are returned [better to verify that by hovering over the operator and checking the executed query].
The second remote operator of the HAVING plan, pulls again all rows from the remote side, hash matches them with the local IRIS table, sorts the hashmatch output and the results of the two steps (being sorted) are merge joined and aggregated.
The main benefit from this, is that the remote side is accessed only two times and the effort of a join is provided by the remote side.

For the WHERE plan, the filter is passed through(?) to the other side, but only for one table (remote query 97%--> filter --> merge). There is a question-mark here, because if the filter/WHERE value was passed through to the linked server the filter operator shouldn't be there, the remote operator would return only the qualifying rows (if the filter was actually passed through). Maybe this is the worst case scenario, where ALL rows from the remote table are pulled in, and then filtered at the local side. The same done for the second table (remote query 0%), merged joined (at the local server) and hash matched with the local table IRIS. At this point, the main difference between HAVING and WHERE is who is doing the joins.

HAVING --> joins two tables at the remote side

WHERE --> pulls remote rows and joins them locally

The most "tricky" operator, could be the third remote query (cost 2%) of the WHERE plan, in the inner part of the nested loops. The "course" of this operator depends on the number of outer rows of the nested loop. If there are 1, 2, 3 rows to be iterated then 1-3 remote queries wouldn't hurt (unless they perform all kind of full scans on the remote side, less likely). However, if the nested loops has to iterate through couple of thousands rows, then each iteration is a query to the linked server and this can be very costly (you could verify that by looking at the number of actual number of rows in the actual execution plan).

With a first glance, at the two execution plans, the performance difference could be explained by the join effort. HAVING requires less effort locally, so it is faster.

This does not mean that a filter on the WHERE couldn't be faster. This could also be the idea of your colleague, who wrote the script, because he is using nested joins

```
FROM TABLE1 TB1
JOIN 
( TABLE2 TB2
  JOIN TABLE3 TB3 ON TB1.SOME_ID = TB2.SOME_ID
)  ON TB1.SOME_ID = TB3.SOME_ID
WHERE TB1.SOME_ID = 9999999
```

This seems intentional, especially if the following is true: local table TB1, remote tables TB2&TB3.

The ideal execution, would be a mashup of the two execution plans (join of two tables at the remote side but with a predicate, i.e a filtered value)
You could try and change the query applying the filter explicitly in the nested query

```
FROM TABLE1 TB1
JOIN 
( TABLE2 TB2
  JOIN TABLE3 TB3 ON TB1.SOME_ID = TB2.SOME_ID **AND TB2.SOME_ID = 9999999**
)  ON TB1.SOME_ID = TB3.SOME_ID
WHERE TB1.SOME_ID = 9999999
```

and maybe explicitly FORCE ORDER and see if it makes any difference.

I hope the above, makes some sense.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with ***In general, the filter on the where clause should be faster, especially with aggregations***. I thought you cannot have aggregates in the WHERE. That is what the HAVING is for? The other info is interesting though and some of it is a bit above my head but sounds compelling. I will have to look into it further when I have a chance.